# How can I handle confirm return in async method

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have an "ic" value in the list and a predefined "og" value assigned to the button.
Those values match in another table. I send to PHP file via ajax and I want it to confirm from the user the value in the result returned with ajax as a message.
If cancel will return false and interrupt the process, but I don't know why couldn't succeed.

How can I handle confirm(sttMsg) and stop button action?

```js
function statusMethod() {
  var sttMsg = "";

  jQuery.each(rows, function(rowid, row) {
    var ic = row.cat_a_req___task_status_raw;

    var og = 'close';
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/spc/statusCheck/check.php",
      data: {
        incoming: ic,
        outgoing: og
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        sttMsg = data.checkMsg;
      },
      async: false
    });
    return confirm(sttMsg);
  });
}

return statusMethod();
```

Comment: **NB:** Synchronous AJAX requests are strongly discouraged. They cause your page/browser to freeze until the request has finished. You should rewrite your code to work with asynchronous requests instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you question is about how to find out which button the user clicked in the `confirm()` dialog box and how to take an action based on that.

You need to save the result of the `confirm()` function to a variable and check its value, like this:

```js
const result = confirm("What would you like to do?");
if (result) {
  console.log(`User confirmed. Value of result is ${result}`);
} else {
  console.log(`User canceled. Value of result is ${result}`);
}
```

In your code, it would be something like this:

```js
function statusMethod() {
  var sttMsg ="";

  jQuery.each(rows, function(rowid, row) {
    var ic = row.cat_a_req___task_status_raw;

    var og = 'close';
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/spc/statusCheck/check.php",
      data: {incoming : ic, outgoing: og},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        sttMsg = data.checkMsg;
      },
      async: false
    });

    const r = confirm(sttMsg);
    if (r) {
      // Do something if user clicks OK
    } else {
      // Do something if the user clicks Cancel
    }
  });
}

return statusMethod();
```

You can read more about the `confirm()` function here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Another possible issue with your code is that you are not handling failures in the request. In that case, you would not have the `sttMsg` variable defined and your code would throw a `ReferenceError` when reaching the `confirm(sttMsg)` function call.

**UPDATE**

If you want to execute that when a button is clicked, you can do it this way:

```js
function statusMethod() {
  var sttMsg = "Do you agree?";
  const r = confirm(sttMsg);
  if (r) {
    // Do something if user clicks OK
  } else {
    // Do something if the user clicks Cancel
  }
  console.log(`Result: ${r}`);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="statusMethod()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I need only true false value. statusMethod function working on buttonAction. for e.g. <button onclick="function(); return statusMethod()";>

Comment: @TanÇetin, I updated the response with an example of how to call a function from a button click, if that's what you were looking for